# Can not call external URLs from docker compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

For local development, using docker compose, everything was working fine, but few days ago started to get this error when trying to authenticate a user.

*The GUID is replaced here to {TenantId}:*

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I created a separate app just to make the call to this url, and noticed that it only give an error when running inside docker-compose, if running just as a single docker container it run with no issues. It seems to be a docker-compose issue as it some times work for few minutes then start to show the error again. Tried on a separate fresh installed laptop and got the same results.

Using docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

Is there any known issue, solution or workaround?

Update:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication1/Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

Comment: its unlikely that its not working in compose but with normal docker run since compose is just a wrapper. It results bascially in the same actions being done by the docker engine at the end of the day. However, if you really think its realted to compose, it would be good to show your compose file and the command you run the non compose docker image with so that we could spot any differences or issues.

Comment: is port 53 open ?  "Name or service not known" seems it's not able to do a DNS lookup

Comment: I suspect the issue will sooner or later also show up with a regular docker run. As you say, sometimes it works, and sometimes not with compose. This seems to be an issue with the endpoint you are hitting. Or maybe you are not passing the tenantId properly.

Comment: you can edit your question and include the file there and any other info that may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently and found a couple solutions... I was running an app locally in Docker for Windows. It ran fine in the IDE but threw this error when running in Docker Compose when trying to authenticate with Azure AD. The root of the issue was that the DNS system in docker compose couldn't resolve `login.microsoftonline.com`. Other URLs worked fine, but there's something different about this one.

The initial solution was to configure your service in the compose file with an outside DNS server (google DNS) like this:

```
dns:
  # specifying DNS servers here, as the container seems to have trouble resolving the URL for the Azure AD login site
  - 8.8.8.8
  - 8.8.4.4
```

This created a side-effect for me though... For my particular setup, my app container needed access to a database running outside of the Docker compose setup. My connection string was pointed to `gateway.docker.internal` (the address of my local physical machine). Using the external DNS servers above made this internal Docker reference stop working. I eventually discovered the way around this was to remove the `dns:` section completely and replace it with a `dns_search` entry, to tell Docker which URLs to look up via DNS:

```
dns_search:
  - login.microsoftonline.com
```

The `dns_search` setting wasn't well documented, but seemed to do the trick for me. It resolved the issue of my .Net app not being able to connect to Azure AD, and didn't break my connection string to `gateway.docker.internal`.

**Edit**: the above items didn't seem to help consistently, so I added this entry to create a hosts file entry for the login site:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "login.microsoftonline.com:40.126.29.13"
```

While the IP address could potentially change, this did get things working for me and is good enough for local development.

Comment: Sorry for the late respond on this. But I was able to resolve the issue long time ago and forgot to mention the solution, which is adding the DNS to my local docker-compose file, same as you mentioned in your answer.